# Coq: what is the difference between an FSet and an MSet?

Tags: set, coq

The documentation for [FSets](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.FSets.FSetInterface.html) and [MSets](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.MSets.MSetInterface.html) suggests that they are very similar constructions. How do they differ at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [library](https://coq.inria.fr/library/) description, `MSets` is "a modernization of `FSets`" which is kept around, I suspect, for backwards compatibility.

Comment: [Refman](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual002.html#sec12) contains some more information: "The reason for making `FSets` evolve is that the computational and logical contents were quite intertwined in the original implementation, leading in some cases to longer computations than expected and this problem is solved in the new `MSets` implementation."